# how to get expanded path from `ls -l /a/*/b` to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I created a folder structure like the following

```bsh
mkdir -p test/f{1..4}/inside
```

while running `ls -l test/*/` i got

```bsh
test/f1/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 s  ff  68 Jun 21 18:37 inside

test/f2/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 s  ff  68 Jun 21 18:37 inside

test/f3/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 s  ff  68 Jun 21 18:37 inside

test/f4/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 s  ff  68 Jun 21 18:37 inside
```

How do I get the expanded paths ( like `test/f1/:`) in a variable, for using it in a loop to do further logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't want to loop through a variable containing "multiple items" (A variable can only contain a single item). Especially not if you are using bash or another shell that supports arrays.

You can set an array with these directories like so:

```
array=( test/*/ )
```

Then to loop through them:

```
$ for item in "${array[@]}"; do printf '\n%s\n' "Current directory: $item"; ls -l "$item"; done

Current directory: test/f1/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 jessebutryn staff 64 Jun 21 07:20 inside

Current directory: test/f2/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 jessebutryn staff 64 Jun 21 07:20 inside

Current directory: test/f3/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 jessebutryn staff 64 Jun 21 07:20 inside

Current directory: test/f4/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 jessebutryn staff 64 Jun 21 07:20 inside
```

However you could also just loop through them directly like so:

```
for item in test/*/; do
    #something with "$item"
done
```

Note: I would always recommend using the full path to things rather than the relative path

```
for item in /path/to/test/*/; do
    #something with "$item"
done
```

This is especially safer when you are globbing

Comment: I want the contents listed by  `ls -l` and the header in separate variables inside same loop

Comment: @san45: Probably an x-y problem.  What ultimately do you need to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I want to loop through the file descriptors in `/proc/*/fd` and list the pid then and only fd of (deleted) files in a formatted way

Comment: What deleted files?

Comment: @san45 `find /proc/[0-9]*/fd -lname '* (deleted)' -printf '%p\t%l\n' 2>/dev/null | sed
 's,^/proc/\([^/]*\)/fd/,\1 ,'`

Comment: @san45 You are explaining an issue that you did not ask about. Please search the site for question relating to listing deleted but open files instead, or ask a new question if you can't find anything. Jesse have correctly answered the question as it was stated.